# Implement react-mobile-datepicker using redux-form

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, redux-form

I have issue with date picker implementation. I am using this date picker:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mobile-datepicker
I am also using redux-form.

Could someone check my code and give me some tips what might be wrong.

It is doing nothing. No error, nothing is happening.

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import DatePicker from 'react-mobile-datepicker';

 renderDatePicker = () => <DatePicker dateConfig={dateConfig} showCaption={true} />

<Field
  name="date"
  type="date"
  component={this.renderDatePicker}
  label={"date"}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage the attribute `isOpen` in `<DatePicker>`, which has the control over the display of the component.
If  `isOpen` is `true`, it is visible else it's invisible.

So in `<DatePicker>` manage the attribute `isOpen` by maintaining state and further like,

```
<DatePicker isOpen={this.state.isOpen} dateConfig={dateConfig} showCaption={true} />
```